# transform.LookAt(targetarget); How not look at, but look like from mirror? mirror

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to explay. I created a mirror with camera and output image from this on texture. I drop the script with transform.LookAt(target); And it`s work fine. But I want to make it work like the mirror. I mean when player look at camera, it must turn out of player on angle what player looks on mirror. I am trying to create copy of target(Transform) and change properties of this. But it unsuccessful.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MirroringAngle : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform target;
public Transform mirror;
private Transform reflectedObject;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
    
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 inDirection = target.transform.position;
    Vector3 inNormal = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    Vector3 reflectedDir = Vector3.Reflect( inDirection, inNormal);
    mirror.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(reflectedDir, 
    Vector3.right);
    transform.LookAt(reflectedDir);
}
}
```

Still look at player

Comment: so you want that if character looks right on to the mirror, the camera looks left?

Comment: If you don't mind doing an extra step, you can just get the rotation given by the LookAt and then apply 180 degrees over the rotation, thus making it look to the opposite direction.

Comment: Lotan, i tried to do everything accord with this page https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html, but adding LookAt(Transform target, Vector3 worldUp = Vector3.up); did not bring the result I need. I also tryed anower axises

Comment: Ramon de Llano, how to do this, I did not understand

Answer (score 0):

I think that to achieve your direction you need to [reflect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html) the players direction to the mirror.

```
Vector3 inDirection = targer.transform.position;
Vector3 inNormal = mirror.Transform.forward;
Vector3 reflectedDir = Vector3 Reflect(Vector3 inDirection, Vector3 inNormal);
```

then you can use [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) for the mirror camera or gameobject to look in that direction.

```
mirror.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(reflectedDir, Vector3.up)
```

Edit: Find full script working:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtReflectedDir : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform source;
    public Transform mirror;
    //private Transform reflectedObject;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 inDirection = mirror.transform.position - source.transform.position;
        Vector3 inNormal = mirror.forward;
        Vector3 reflectedDir = Vector3.Reflect(inDirection, inNormal);
        mirror.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(reflectedDir, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Mirror in normal pos:
[image]

Mirror looking to the reflected dir:

[image]

Comment: Vector3 inNormal = mirror.Transform.Normal; Transform does not contain Normal. I updated my scrip, but it still dont work properly

Comment: I meant `forward`, meaning the current direction the mirror is facing to, corrected in the answer

Comment: I attached the working script, as the code was containig some small mistakes. I provided it to give you the idea. I think yo do not need to create the `private Transform reflectedObject;` but just to make the mirror look in the reflected direction if I understood correctly

Comment: Thanks, it was trash from previus variant))

Comment: mirror.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(reflectedDir, Vector3.up); Camera spinning around with it. It`s looks like I need to create Transform reflected object and send it to LookAt()

Comment: But it not possible to do this in script. Most simply way I see it create empty gameObject, which will move in same way with player but with -, and LookAt this

Comment: I dont understand your camera spinnig problem. The script I provide, makes the mirror look in the reflected direction taking a source position. I changed the name from target to source because I find it less confusing.

Comment: If you attach the corresponding gameobjects in the public fields you get the look at reflected direction I think you want. If its not your exact use case hope that this example helps to achieve it

Comment: I don't understend why, but it spining. I do not understend one thing. You put the logic in start(). I tried too, but it don't work at all, and it looks like correct as I see. Are you tried to test this script? I saw what someone solves mirror reflection problem with reflection Probe. May be I should try this. I will write if it will result in success.

Comment: yes the images show the script in actionin play mode. You need to attach dragging the components in to the public fields in the editor to the mirror and source in the editor, have you done that? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Yes, I attached source and mirror. No errors. But I put logic in update(). It rotates. If I put logic in start() nothing happens

Comment: the start is only executed once at the start. The update is executed constantly

Comment: Yes. So why logic in start()?

Comment: it depends on if you one your mirror to be orientated onli once at the beggining or to be continously updated. This depends on what you want  for your specific use of this, moreover the question is regarding the direction the mirror should look at, so this out of the scope of the question.